# Session is Closed! NHibernate shouldn't be trying to grab data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, nhibernate, eager-loading

I have a UnitOfWork/Service pattern where I populate my model using NHibernate before sending it to the view.  For some reason I still get the YSOD, and I don't understand why the object collection is not already populated.

My controller method looks like this:

```
public ActionResult PendingRegistrations()
{
    var model = new PendingRegistrationsModel();
    using (var u = GetUnitOfWork())
    {
        model.Registrations = u.UserRegistrations.GetRegistrationsPendingAdminApproval();
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

The service/unit of work looks like this:

```
public partial class NHUserRegistrationRepository : IUserRegistrationRepository
{
    public IEnumerable<UserRegistration> GetRegistrationsPendingAdminApproval()
    {
        var r =
            from UserRegistration ur in _Session.Query<UserRegistration>()
            where ur.Status == AccountRegistrationStatus.PendingAdminReview
            select ur;
        NHibernateUtil.Initialize(r);
        return r;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You could try to set the collection as `.Not.LazyLoad()`

Comment: You mean in the mapping?  I did try that, but it didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: What is the value of r before the call to NHibernateUtil.Initialize()?

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs I'm sorry, yes, I meant on the mapping. I believe you could try setting all the collections as not lazy, but you should consider the performance implications

Comment: @AndreCalil, yeah that would not be practical.  On the other hand, all properties on this entity should always be fetched eagerly.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs Well, so set them all as not lazy and give a try. I believe that this is the reason that's causing NH to fetch them on the session again.

Comment: @Maciej, if I put a break point right after the query, I get back a couple of results.

Comment: @AndreCalil is there a way to set all the properties Not.LazyLoad() without putting it on every mapping?  I tried just putting it in the mapping constructor but that didn't do anything.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs AFAIK you must add it to each mapping statement that is not a simple value (that is, which relates with other object)

Comment: @AndreCalil that's the maddening thing about this; this object has no relation to any other entities.  It's completely standalone.  I don't understand why it's not loading the collection and staying loaded.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs I agree, that's awkward. Sorry, what does `NHibernateUtil.Initialize(r);` do?

Comment: @AndreCalil As I understand it, it is supposed to eagerly fetch the data in the graph; in actuality, it seems to do nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are having is no different than the problem you would have with any other LINQ provider.  You need to execute your query in order to get the results.  If you don't have a valid context, that won't work.

This problem is easy to fix without condemning LINQ to NHibernate.  Just change

```
public IEnumerable<UserRegistration> GetRegistrationsPendingAdminApproval()
{
    var r =
        from UserRegistration ur in _Session.Query<UserRegistration>()
        where ur.Status == AccountRegistrationStatus.PendingAdminReview
        select ur;
    NHibernateUtil.Initialize(r);
    return r;
}
```

to

```
public IEnumerable<UserRegistration> GetRegistrationsPendingAdminApproval()
{
    var r =
        from UserRegistration ur in _Session.Query<UserRegistration>()
        where ur.Status == AccountRegistrationStatus.PendingAdminReview
        select ur;
    NHibernateUtil.Initialize(r);
    return r.ToList();
}
```

Comment: So it does.  I was unaware of this.  I had tried `.AsEnumerable` without success.  Thanks for your answer.

Comment: So simple yet so pretty. +1 for the explanation